# How to fix permissions error with prestashop on centos 7 apache?

Tags: php, centos, prestashop

Installing Prestashop 1.7.6.2
An error has occured:

> You need to grant write permissions for PHP on the following directory: /var/www/html/presta

This error appears while installing Prestashop. It's staying with 0%.

I have:

- centos 7
- PHP 7.3.14

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make /var/www/html/presta writable.  Using chmod 1777 /var/www/html/presta or chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/presta should do the trick.  Please note www-data is the apache user for ubuntu and your user and group may be different.  You should review [Linux Permissions](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html) to get a better understanding of what is going on.  Making stuff writable on the webserver can be potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change var/www/html/presta owner to www-data if you're using apache or to nginx if you're using nginx.

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/presta`

But DO NOT change permissions to 777 since this wil open your site completely, change directories to 0755 and files to 0644 instead.

Inside shop root folder:

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 -- {} +` to set proper permissions for all files

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 -- {} +` to set proper permissions for all directories

`chmod 666 .htaccess` to set proper permissions for .htaccess

Comment: check what user apache is running with, on some system it may be user nobody. Run this command to set the user, ```ps aux | egrep --color '([a|A]pache|[h|H]ttpd|[n|N]ginx)'``` then chown -R the var/www directory to that user.

Comment: I have the same issue. **CentOS 7 + PHP 7.2.**
I've set 755 + 644 + apache:apache, and even with 777 I still have this message:
`You need to grant write permissions for PHP on the following directory: /var/www/html/shop`

Comment: If the apache is the webserver user indeed, make sure that it owns recursively from /var/www down.

Answer (score 0):

I've used apache:apache and somehow it's working. But right now i've got another problem:
PrestaShop installation needs to write critical files in the folder var/cache. Please review the permissions on your server.

Comment: I bet you'll find in var/cache directories and files owned by root... they of course need the same apache ownership.